# sc-finality-grandpa issue in my node-template v0.9.37

Tags: substrate-node-template

I am trying to compile the `polkadot-v0.9.37` version of node-template with some added customisations.

I run `cargo update` and get this issue in the core pallets:

```
error: no matching package named `sc-finality-grandpa` found
location searched: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git
required by package `node-template v4.0.0-dev (/Users/ramsey/decentration/substrate-supersig-template/node)`
```

issue can be replicated [here](https://github.com/decentration/substrate-supersig-template/tree/v0.9.37).

Answer (score 2):

There was a space " branch" in the Cargo.toml. Quickly resolved.